# Replace "Choose One" with another text programmatically

Tags: wicket, dropdownchoice

I need to replace the "Choose One" text in a `DropDownChoice` with another text programmatically. (I.e. I can't put the replacement text in a .properties file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787656/in-the-wicket-dropdownchoice-how-can-you-replace-choose-one-to-another-text).) How do I achieve this?

To give a little context, I have objects that looks roughly like

```
FruitOption
    "No fruit chosen"
    Orange
    Banana

AnimalOption
    "No animal chosen"
    Dog
    Cat
```

and the *`"No _____ chosen"`* string is part of the option-object and loaded from database.

I realize I could use a null object pattern, and give the null-object a special treatment in the ChoiceRenderer, but I'd prefer not to because the choice-objects are of an abstract type that's inconvenient to create a dummy-object for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the following NULL-oriented methods are declared in: `AbstractSingleSelectChoice` (see [the online JavaDoc](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSingleSelectChoice.html) ), which is the super-class of: `DropDownChoice`. You may define any of the related `String` values in your component or use a formatted message based on properties. Review the methods to understand how they work and then replace the example implementations with whatever fits your needs:

```
/**
 * Returns the display value for the null value.
 * The default behavior is to look the value up by
 * using the key retrieved by calling: <code>getNullValidKey()</code>.
 *
 * @return The value to display for null
 */
protected String getNullValidDisplayValue() {
    String option = 
            getLocalizer().getStringIgnoreSettings(getNullValidKey(), this, null, null);
    if (Strings.isEmpty(option)) {
        option = getLocalizer().getString("nullValid", this, "");
    }
    return option;
}

/**
 * Return the localization key for the nullValid value
 * 
 * @return getId() + ".nullValid"
 */
protected String getNullValidKey() {
    return getId() + ".nullValid";
}

/**
 * Returns the display value if null is not valid but is selected.
 * The default behavior is to look the value up by using the key
 * retrieved by calling: <code>getNullKey()</code>.
 *
 * @return The value to display if null is not valid but is
 *     selected, e.g. "Choose One"
 */
protected String getNullKeyDisplayValue() {
    String option =
            getLocalizer().getStringIgnoreSettings(getNullKey(), this, null, null);

    if (Strings.isEmpty(option)) {
        option = getLocalizer().getString("null", this, CHOOSE_ONE);
    }
    return option;
}

/**
 * Return the localization key for null value
 * 
 * @return getId() + ".null"
 */
protected String getNullKey() {
    return getId() + ".null";
}
```